# How to test the right-associativity of conditional operator in c#

Tags: c#

I wrote the following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xyz = 10 < 11 ? 12 : 5 < 21 ? getValue() : 15;
    Console.WriteLine(xyz);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int getValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
    return 100;
}
```

Since the first condition is always true, the value that xyz will get is 12 but since the conditional operator is itself right associative, I was expecting that the getValue() function would be executed first and "hello" would be printed. When I run this code, it doesn't run that way.

Can someone please enlighten me on this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
var xyz = 10 < 11 ? 12 : 5 < 21 ? getValue() : 15;
```

is treated as:

```
var xyz = 10 < 11 ? 12 : (5 < 21 ? getValue() : 15);
```

So we have a conditional expression with:

- Condition: `10 < 11`
- First branch: `12`
- Second branch: `5 < 21 ? getValue() : 15`

As `10 < 11` is true, the first branch is evaluated but the second branch is not.

The associativity isn't as easily shown with your code as with code which uses a `bool` expression for every operand - as that could compile with either associativity.

Consider this code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {            
    var xyz = Log(1, true) ? Log(2, true) : Log(3, true) ? Log(4, false) : Log(5, true);
  }

  static bool Log(int x, bool result)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Renaming each `Log(x, ...)` to `Lx` for simplicity, we have:

```
var xyz = L1 ? L2 : L3 ? L4 : L5;
```

That could be handled as:

```
// Right associativity
var xyz = L1 ? L2 : (L3 ? L4 : L5);

// Left associativity
var xyz = (L1 ? L2 : L3) ? L4 : L5;
```

Given the results we're returning, with right-associativity we'd expect to see output of 1, 2. With left-associativity, we'd see 1, 2, 4. The actual output is 1, 2, showing right-associativity.

Comment: Thank you Jon. Actually I found in one of the article stating "The assignment, compound assignment, lambda, null coalescing, and conditional operators are right-associative, and so these are evaluated from right to left. For instance, `x = y = z` is evaluated as `x = (y = z)` and `a ? b : c ? d : e` as `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` ". So I am trying to work out an example for the same.

Comment: Since Grouping has higher precedence than the conditional operator, I am expecting an output of 3,4,1,2 for the right associative case. Can you please point out where is my thought process going wrong!

Comment: @Prashant: I don't know what you mean by "grouping has higher precedence" - "grouping" isn't an operator; there's no such precedence.

Comment: @Prashant: Why would it log 3 first? Do you understand that the conditional operator always evaluates the first operand, and only then decides whether to evaluate the second operand or the third operand? My example shows precisely your `a ? b : c ? d : e` case.

Answer (score 1):

If you translate the code into in..else statement, it would be -

```
        int xyz = 0;
        if (10 < 11)
        {
            xyz = 12;
        }
        else
        {
            if (5 < 21)
            {
                xyz = getValue();
            }
            else
            {
                xyz = 15;
            }
        }
```

And since the first if condition evaluates to true, the else will not execute and you will get 12 printed on console.